# What is the suggested action for users that post comments as answers?

Tags: discussion

Most of these users are looking at our site to post a comment - which is harmless, but they usually only have one reputation. So, instead of doing this they instead end up in the review queue with a very short "answer".

How can we prevent this? To my knowledge, the 50 reputation minimum is a SE imposed limitation - but it does seem to make things a tad bit more complicated than need be. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 7):

It is intended to keep the signal-to-noise ratio high. The SE sites try to minimize discussion, and the comment system is really only intended to get further clarification on questions / answers.

In the case of when this is done, moderators possess the ability to convert an answer to a comment. You just need to flag it when necessary, of course, it's not necessary in the case of every comment.

Answer (score 4):

Downvote the answer and flag it for deletion as "not an answer." That's the best way to handle these sorts of things.